# Escape <%%> In jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have a field helper jsp file which churns out code for various components. The field helper jsp returns a string which is used by another jsp, which shall be called foo. I need to have the scriplet tags in foo in order to call the URLEncoder encode method. Unfortunately, the field helper jsp is causing errors due to the <% %> in htmlString. Is there any way to escape the <% %> tags in a jsp?

Tech: struts 1.3 & jdk 1.7 
excerpt of field helper jsp

```
<% 
//do stuff here
htmlString.append("<TD> <A HREF=\"fileDownload.jsp?filename=<%=URLEncoder.encode("+example+")%>\" TARGET=\"_BLANK\"> "+foo+" </A></TD>");
return htmlString;%>
```

I have already tried the following escapes:

```
\<% %\n 
<\% \%>
\<\% \%\>
```

Comment: I'm guessing, but would `&gt;` or `&lt;` work?

Comment: You don't even need to, and if you could, you can't nest evaluations like this anyway.

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you building HTML in scriptlets?

Comment: Don't ask me why the original programmers originally built HTML in scriplets...this is legacy code for work and unless I redo 50 + jsp files then I need to continue to build the HTML in a scriplet @DaveNewton

Comment: You can't redo them as you go?! Hm. Well, enjoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any need to do so, you can call `URLEncoder.encode(String)` directly. Something like

```
htmlString.append("<TD> <A HREF=\"fileDownload.jsp?filename=" 
        + URLEncoder.encode(example) + "\" TARGET=\"_BLANK\">" 
        + foo + " </A></TD>");
```